# Re-ordering box plots by mean in R

Tags: r, mean, boxplot

I have some code to plot boxplots for 150 variables, each with 3 replicates. This works no problem, but I want to reorder them so they appear from lowest mean to highest mean along the x-axis. Any suggestions on what I can use to do this?

Comment: If you are using the `tidyverse`, have a look at `fct_reorder`.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. We'd only be able to give vague suggestions without seeing data and code. Also take a look again at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can order the variables according to their mean value by just writing:

`ordered.names = names(df)[order(colMeans(df))]`

Then, you'll know the order in which you have to draw them and can use this order in the loop you use to draw the plots or to reorder the data.frame itself (`df = df[,ordered.names])`)